# Magento - add customer company to address in order validation email

Tags: magento

I want to add the customer company to address in order validation email.

How can I do that ?

I have tried this code :

```
<html><![CDATA[{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}<br/>
{{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}<br />{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}<br/>
{{var country}}<br/>
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}]]></html>
```

in the file

> app/code/core/Customer/etc/config.xml

but it show the correct address only in cart and not in Emails.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The company address is not on the customer record, it is on the billing/shipping address. This could have something to do with it.

For that reason you may want to try adding the company as a custom field to the customer record:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/customers_and_accounts/registration_fields

Or, if you want a quick and dirty solution, you can rename Fax to company and edit your forms and .csv files accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use the company field that already exists in customer address in backend

Comment: The company being on the address record makes a lot of sense when more than one company is in a building. A lot has changed on 1.5 - it has features to set this up in the backend that I have not seen before. What version are you on?